# CSS Flexbox image scale based on side content

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm kinda stuck and don't know if flexbox can do what I need. The idea is to have an image on the left and some content on the right. The image on the left must take its height based on the content on the right and scale to keep it's ratio. If the content is to big, having a max-height would be great but not mandatory.

Here is an image of the main idea :
[image]

Here is my current code where the image takes its natural height and doesn't shrink to the right content like I need :

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper > img {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper > div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/20/13/19/city-731219_960_720.jpg">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nec accumsan risus. Nullam sagittis cursus egestas. Cras scelerisque nibh et massa suscipit, ut viverra.</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: the width where the image need to belong should be fixed?

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zu361oyx/ ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean, But the image should scale keeping its ratio based on the height of the content so the width is dynamic

Comment: @TemaniAfif no the width must adapt, see my previuous comment

Comment: then it's impossible, if the height should be based on the text then we need to first know the height of the text so the width of the text need to be known too. If later you adapt the height of the image to the height of the text AND you want the width to adapt again then you will change the width of the text which will change its height again .. you are trapped inside an infinite loop